# Connecting to External API on Virtual Machine via Docker

Tags: docker

I have an API that exists on an external machine(let's call it: exmachine). The API itself has its own address(let's call it: http://10.10.10.10:8000).

I need use a local Docker container to connect to this external API. I think the best way to do this would be to create an nginx container and have the plug in the API address and machine name into the nginx.conf file. But I am unsure how that would work remotely.

Would anyone know the best method to connect to an external API via Docker? Much appreicated.

Comment: Just calling it directly should work; is there a specific problem you’re encountering?

Comment: So running something like this would work? docker -d -p 10.10.10.10:8000:80 <imagename>

Comment: You don't need any special `-p` option (that's only for inbound connections to the container).  Just make an outbound HTTP connection as normal.

Comment: That makes sense, would you mind providing some documentation on how to make an outbound HTTP request from Docker? I'm somewhat of a novice with Docker.